# Taking two sets (A, B) out of the same distribution, merging and then sorting should roughly result in a,b,a,b,a,b?

Tags: distributions, randomness, runs

Suppose I take 2 sets ($A$ and $B$) of 1000 random items out the same distribution; I also suppose that all items are different.
I then create a new set $C$ which is the union of $A$ and $B$, since all items are different it has 2000 elements.
If $C$ is sorted (ascending or descending), should I roughly end up with a sequence: $a_0,b_1,a_2,b_3,a_4,b_5,...a_i,b_j,...b_{2000}$ ($a_i$ is an element of $A$ and $b_j$ is an element of $B$?

Or alternatively should the number of runs (defined by Wald-Wolfowitz) be almost equal to number of elements in $C$? Here a run is a follow up of elements from the same set.  For example:

- $a,b,a,b$ has 4 runs
- $a,a,a,b,b$ has 2 runs
- $a,b,b,b,a,a$ has 3 runs

If this would not be case, what's the reason behind it?

To give a more practical setting, I also implemented this now and asked it on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645350/combining-two-samples-out-of-numpy-random-does-not-end-up-in-a-random-sequence?).

Comment: Some or same?  Either way there is not information to determine the sequence.

Comment: The same distribution, I changed it.

Comment: This seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @gung Do you know what the other eliminates in the sets are either before or after they are merged?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm not sure what you mean, but when the sets are merged, the union is taken and no elements are eliminated.

Comment: I think the question has changed considerably.  Is a the only element in A and b the only element in B?  If so the union of the two sets is just {a, b}. I don't think the Wald-Wolfowitz run test came up in the original question. I am still puzzled as to how the elements are randomly drawn.  Are you drawing them out of C 1000 times?  If so is this done without replacement? I still don't see how the question is clear and I don't see what interpretation is being used by those who gave answers.

Comment: I made the confusion around the union clear. The elements are drawn like you would do with python: `A = np.random.chisquare(1, 1000)` and `B = np.random.chisquare(1, 1000)`.

Comment: This is the situation analyzed in the first page of Part I of A. M. Mood, *The Distribution Theory of Runs* (1940): https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731825.

Comment: Consider this thought experiment: watch the sequence as it is created. At any stage, roughly half the sequence consists of $a$'s and half of $b$'s. Until the end, there is about a 1/2 chance that the next element in the sequence will be an $a$ and a 1/2 chance it will be a $b$, and there is a 1/2 chance the *current* element is an $a$ and 1/2 chance it is a $b$. Therefore there is a 1/2 chance that the next element will be the same as the current element--continuing a run--and a 1/2 chance it will be different, creating a new run. Thus the expected number of runs is close to $2000/2=1000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool question! If we generalize your framework and let $n$ represent the number of items in each set, then we can make some headway toward finding the solution. In your case $n = 1000$. But what if we let $n = 1$? There are always ${2n} \choose {n}$ total arrangements so in the simplest case where $n=1$, there are just two possibilities. Both have 2 runs. Now, consider $n=2$. There are ${2n} \choose {n}$ $= 6$ arrangements and the average number of runs is exactly 3. Going further, $n=3$ leads to 20 arrangements and an average of 4 runs. At this point, it seems unlikely that the answer will ever differ from $n+1$ as the average number of runs. This can probably be proved by induction pretty easily.

Comment: your answer actually says I'm wrong because it would mean I end up on average with a,a,b,b,a,a,b,b ... because C has 2000 elements in it and not 1000?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. A and B both have 1000 elements. C is a concatenation of the two which is subsequently permuted randomly. Thus, C has 2000 elements. You're original guess of an average number of runs of 1000 was wrong...but just barely. The answer is actually 1001.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing your problem to the [Mann-Whitney test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) I guess you are correct, in the sense that the run lengths should not be much different from one. This test is based on summing the ranks of each set (`a` or `b` in your case) and then looking at the difference.